# {NETWORKING} Configuring traffic between devices in different subnets

Tags: networking, routes, ip, ipv4

my network consist of two Fritz! routers, the main one (192.168.188.1) and another that creates a subnet below the previous (192.168.178.1). I'm about to add the IP camera (Unifi G3 Bullet) with the 192.168.178.AAA address but I want it to be accessible by the server with 192.168.188.BBB ip address. Is it something I can achieve by static ipv4 routing in the router settings or something that is rather not possible? How would I go about creating those routes or is there other solution to this problem? [network diagram for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPLtd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solved this problem by opening TCP port 554 for 192.168.178.AAA:554 in the "178" router and than I addressed this cammera in the main router network by 192.168.188.(sub-router IP in main network):554 and it works flawlessly.